# Setting properties in laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the the following Post model.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'app_id',
        'title',
        'content'
  ];

    private $app_id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->app_id = 43;
    }

}
```

I am trying to save a new post with the following code:

```
  $post = new Post();
  $post->title="Test title";
  $post->content="Test content";
  $post->save();
```

This gets saved, however the app_id isn't getting saved. Any ideas why it doesn't simply get set when I new up the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->attributes['app_id'] = 43;
```

Comment: Thanks Niketan Raval that has fixed it, however not sure why what I had doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't define **private $app_id;**. If you do that, Laravel's magic methods will not work when you try to set the value on the 'app_id' attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this also:

```php
$model->setAttribute('price', 500);
```